# How to set list property with swagger block on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

I use `swagger-blocks` gem on a Rails app.

Want to set a list property but didn't find it in the swagger official data types:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

- string
- number
- integer
- boolean
- array
- object

For example, the response data will be:

```
{
    "posts": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Tried:

```
response 200 do
  schema do
    property :posts do
      key :type, :string
    end
  end
end
```

It's string.

Comment: have you consult this example https://github.com/fotinakis/swagger-blocks in this ` swagger_path '/pets'` check this example of fetching all pets.

Comment: @NN796 Yes, I have checked that. But still have no idea for my special need. Even looked through this example: http://petstore.swagger.io/#/

Comment: what is your special need?

Comment: @NN796 As my question. Helen had answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to change the type of `posts` from a string to an array of integer:

```ruby
response 200 do
  schema do
    property :posts do
      key :type, :array
      items do
        key :type, :integer
      end
    end
  end
end
```